# mix-blend-mode: multiply rending incorrectly?

Tags: css, colors, rendering, blending

I'm working on a logo that uses the multiply blending mode with a red shape and a blue shape to create a very specific grey in the space where the colour is multiplied.

In all graphic editing software I try, the results are the same:
[image]

**R**255 **G**38 **B**30

x

**R**30 **G**200 **B**255

=

**R**30 **G**30 **B**30

---

But the results I get using css are very different. Using the code below, these same two colours colours end up multiplying to this weird, red-shifted colour of **R**87 **G**49 **B**47

```
.red, .blue {
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.red {
background: rgb(255,38,30);
}
.blue {
background: rgb(30,200,255);
}
```

[image]

Why is it that the browser is interpreting these colours differently, even though it should be a straight multiplication of RGB values?

You can see a working example at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/sambar/pen/XYxZzM?editors=1100).

Comment: It's working fine for me and I obtain the good color .. in your codepen there is more CSS involved which may affect the rendring ... Create a minimal example and see

Comment: in the graphic editing software are both layers (red and blue) have blending set to multiply or just the top layer? In your css they are both multiplying. Also, this is a non-standard property I believe... IE doesn't support it

Comment: @zgood I guess each one will multiply with the bottom layer ... so the first one will mutiply with the white backroung (nothing will happen, the color will remain the same) then the top layer will multiply with the bottom one which will be good

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9Lz0tupm/1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif got ya... makes sense

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don¡'t know if it is relevant, but the fiddle has some masking set.

Comment: @TemaniAfif in your fiddle, the resulting color is still the red-shifted one: http://oi66.tinypic.com/1y20lc.jpg

Comment: this is what I have : https://imgur.com/a/herNS8Y ... I have the right color

Comment: @vals yes his codepen has some masking and other CSS which may create the issue that why I asked for a minimal example

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hmmm, odd that your fiddle is rendering differently between us, might this be a difference in rendering engine issue? I'm assuming the original pen (yes yes, the masking) does show incorrectly for you though?

Comment: yes the pen is not like the screenshot here ... I see a light color in the intersection